# Making a C++ max function for an array: What is the proper way to handle the case of the array size being 0?

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I need a function that returns the maximum value of an array.

If the array is empty, then there is no maximum value. What is the proper C++ way of handling that?

I can think of a few ways. I'm wondering which would be considered "most proper" from the perspective of a C++ Nazi, and why?

(1)

Use

```
template <class T>
T max(T* arrPtr, size_t n)
{
    if (n == 0)
       throw ("Can't have the max of an empty array, you idiot.")
    T highest = *arrPtr
    for (T* i(arrPtr), j(arrPtr + n); i != j; ++i)
       if (*i > highest)
          highest = *i;
    return highest;
}
```

(2)

Use

```
template <class T>
bool max (T* arrPtr, size_t n, T highest)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (T* i(arrPtr), j(arrPtr + n); i != j; ++i)
            if (*i > highest)
                highest = *i;
        return true;
    }
}
```

(3)

Use some fancy 1-line block of code that the geniuses at StackOverflow are about to post.

Comment: I'd ask how often would you expect the array to be empty? If this is an exceptional scenario then the exception is appropriate.

Comment: Another method, not used in C++ much, is to return a [`Maybe`](http://yapb-soc.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/implementing-maybe-monad-in-c.html?m=1)

Comment: I think the C++ way to do this is to take first and last ForwardIterators and return an iterator for the max element, and last if first==last (this is actually this is max_element from <algorithm>).

Comment: Return `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` if the range is empty. You can use this as the initial value of your accumulator, too, so you don't even need to check. (Note that this won't work if `T` can't be default constructed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever in doubt,we should try to understand the C++ STL algorithm interface and how they have written. I believe that this is one of the most elegant C++ code on this planet in every sense. So this is the way your program should be written

```
template <class Iterator>
Iterator max_implem(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    if (first == last) return last;
    // implement your logic
    return last;
}


template <class T>
T max(T* arrPtr, size_t n) {
 T* out = max_implem(arrPtr, arrPtr+n);
 return *out; 
}
```

So in general we should try to return as much information possible from our algorithm so that later it can be used. Returning the iterator(pointer) should be obvious choice in this case.

Comment: `return *out;` causes undefined behaviour if `n == 0`, so this `max()` function still has the same problem OP was asking about!

Answer (score 0):

Both are perfectly valid, in a workable sense, ways of dealing with the problem.

If you are part of team that already has some policies about dealing with such errors, stick with it. If you are not part of such a team or you are trying to come up with a policy, I would recommend adopting the option of `throw`. It provides you the ability to provide a lot more information about the reason for failures.